# Class loading issue after upgrading to TomEE 1.7.1

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, classloader, apache-tomee

I'm upgrading an application from TomEE 1.6.0 to TomEE 1.7.1 and seeing some class loading inconsistencies. The class I'm having problem with is javax.ws.rs.core.Response, which exists in both jsr311-api and javaee-api. In order to troubleshoot the problem I have deployed the same application on two different vagrant instances and did the following:

```
# on TomEE 1.6.0 
find /opt -name "*.jar" | xargs grep javax.ws.rs.core.Response.class
Binary file /opt/cc/tomee/mlsvc/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar matches
Binary file /opt/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.6.0/lib/javaee-api-6.0-5-tomcat.jar matches

#on TomEE 1.7.1
find /opt -name "*.jar" | xargs grep javax.ws.rs.core.Response.class
Binary file /opt/cc/tomee/mlsvc/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar matches
Binary file /opt/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1/lib/javaee-api-6.0-6-tomcat.jar matches
```

On both machines this class exists in two different jars, and from what I read [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html) Tomcat is supposed to load what's in WEB-INF but that's not the case for TomEE 1.7.1. To verify that I ran the application on both VMs with -verbose:class JVM option and this is what I see:

```
#on TomEE 1.6.0
[Loaded javax.ws.rs.core.Response from  file:/opt/cc/tomee/mlsvc/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar]

#on TomEE 1.7.1
[Loaded javax.ws.rs.core.Response from file:/opt/apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.1/lib/javaee-api-6.0-6-tomcat.jar]
```

So TomEE 1.6.0 is loading the correct class from WEB-INF/lib directory but 1.7.1 is loading from the common lib directory and ignoring what's in WEB-INF. I compared catalina.properties on both machines but couldn't see anything that could make a difference. Does anyone have an idea why this could happen?

**EDIT:** I just tried with TomEE 1.7.0, same behavior as 1.7.1

**EDIT:** I checked Tomcat versions: TomEE 1.6.0 has Tomcat 7.0.47 and TomEE 1.7.1 has 7.0.55. This seems like a minor upgrade but I still wonder if anything changed in regards to class loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you shouldnt need this jsr jar in your webapp.

hat said EE APIs are provided by the container and the support of the overloading of the API (what you do) is not mandatory. TomEE is even explicitly skipping this jar (you surely have a message in the logs).

Comment: I understand that it is a better practice to use container provided java-ee api instead of jsr311, but this same thing works fine in TomEE 1.6.0. Is this a behavior change that was introduced by more recent versions? Also, I couldn't find a log that indicates explicitly skipping my jar, where should I look for it?

Comment: well not a best practice it shouldnt be supported (even if some container does, for tomee you can deactivate it when the spec version is not the same as the provided one for most of specs but here you use the same)

this change was introduced cause it was creating too much issues, I cant remember exactly when but potentiall in between 1.6 and 1.7. You should have a log if you grep "contains offending class"